# Putting Cards Into a List of Lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to place cards into a list of 8 empty lists. I need lists 1-4 to have 7 cards each, while lists 5-8 have 6 cards each. I've imported a cards module, I'm just not sure how to have it put a card into the each of the lists in the particular manner I want.

```
import cards
list_of_lists = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
for L in list_of_lists:
    print(L)
```

Currently, I can only print out this:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

How do I fill up each list with cards? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the "cards" module, never heard of it, do you have a link so we can know what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (the get_card() method is here to mock your cards import):

```
def get_card():
    return "spade"

lol = [
    [None] * 7, [None] * 7, [None] * 7, [None] * 7,
    [None] * 6, [None] * 6, [None] * 6, [None] * 6,
]

for l in lol:
    for index, card in enumerate(l):
        l[index] = get_card()

for l in lol:
    print(l)
```

When you run it, the values will look like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyRFU.png)